# Soft deletion with paranoia and factory girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails, ruby-paranoia

When I call delete on records in rspec it seems they are permanently deleted. I assume this has something to do with factory girl. Is there a way to test soft deletion with paranoia, factory girls, rails and rspec without doing anything invasive?

Comment: Are you looking to test the 'destroy' method while using gem paranoia? Just ensure `acts_as_paranoid` is set on the model.

Comment: `delete_all` hard deleted the records for some reason. Set `deleted_at` to some time in a factory reset it to nil somehow. I managed to get it to work by setting a deleted_at after the records had been created, referencing the model and saving the record, but I feel this question is still unanswered.

Comment: It would help to post your spec - what do you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soft delete is triggered by calling destroy, not delete, which skips callbacks.